# Best client for loki-grafana with docker applications in all OS

Tags: docker, logging, grafana, grafana-loki, promtail

I am implementing the loki-grafana log management system and I have several questions.

First of all I want to put you in the context of my environment:

- Applications  in java which log to different files / daemons
- They are in docker linux containers
- These containers can run on a linux/windows/debian OS ....

I guess the right option is to run both Loki and grafana in docker containers on the machine together with the rest of the containers.

My question comes with : Which client do I use to join the logs of my services/applications to loki-grafana? Grafana gives us the following alternatives

1. **Promtail** : This is the default one used by the loki-grafana guide, but I haven't been able or haven't seen yet the way to make it read the log of other applications in docker. I was thinking about doing it sharing volumes with the host, but it seems to me that there may be clients that make this easier for me ...
2. **AWS** : I don't use the cloud, discarded too.
3. **Docker driver** :It is the one that recommends you with docker , but not being able to run plugins on windows is discarded. (Which is a problem)
4. **Fluentbit** : It is a very powerful metrics processor, but in principle I only want to pass the logs to grafana and manage it from loki/grafana. Would I be interested in this option for my case ?
5. **Fluentd** : I find it very similar to logstash , but it seems that you can configure the pass/user which puts it above logstash .
6. **Logstash** : in principle it is linked to Loki and runs the same image seems like a very good option.

Here is the info on the [clients](https://grafana.com/docs/loki/latest/clients/).

Any contribution are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

You can get logs from docker to loki with promtail, you only need to bind logs dir from docker to promtail container an.

Fluent stack works good too, but promtail is more ready to use.